# Use Flow to Create ContentNote and ContentDocumentLink to associate to Account

Tags: flow

Hey I am trying to create a process builder in Salesforce to create a contentnote on an account. However I can't get the flow to work correctly. I can create just a contentnote but when I try and create a contentdocumentlink to associate the note to a record I get an error that has no helpful information. I can't post 3 images but I run the create contentnote step first and assign the recordid to a variable then try and reference that in the next step which is create contentnotedocument

[image]

[image]